# GDI draw barcode text

Tags: c#, drawing, barcode, gdi, system.drawing

I'm trying to use `GDI` in `C#` to draw `Code 128` barcode. I have `.ttf`font which should work as vector graphic (not rastr):

```
        var bmp = new Bitmap(900, 100);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.Clear(Color.White);
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        g.DrawString(value, new Font("Code 128", 72), Brushes.Black, 0, 50);
        g.DrawPath(new Pen(Brushes.Black, (float) 1.0), new GraphicsPath());
        g.Flush();
```

the result image is wide, i want to scale it to 0.5 (x axis only). But when i scale X to 450,- image becomes not clear. I noticed that image (when it still 900) is lightly blurred: 
[image]

i think my broblem will be solved if image will look like here:

[image]

How to draw string in such manner?

Comment: Switch InterpolationMode off as well! The results must fit the nearest pixel.

Comment: Thanks @taw i tried, but result is the same

Comment: These have worked for me: `e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None;
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoothing of text is controlled by the TextRenderingHint property.  Just set this property prior to rendering your string:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;
```